# A phrase misheard as 'San Ababis'

Tags: phrases

I was reading the blog Futility Closet today, and they mentioned a story of a Fillipino father naming his son 'San Ababis', after 'the patron saint of America' - because he heard soldiers repeating those words (and knew San meant Saint)

This was posted on Futility Closet with no explanation as to what he could have been mishearing - perhaps I'm just being silly (or the meaning is obvious to American English speakers and not me as a Scot)

I searched online for other mentionings of the story, however they also had no explanation.

The post is here http://www.futilitycloset.com/2011/05/21/apple-piety-2/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Appears to be a bastardization of "sonofabitch" or "son of a bitch" — excuse the pun.